# None values when calculating the mean and standard deviation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am calculating the mean and standard deviation of the nested data `products` in PySpark DataFrame.

```
+----------+--------------------------------+
|product_PK|                        products|
+----------+--------------------------------+
|      686 |          [[686,520.70],[645,2]]|
|      685 |[[685,45.556],[678,23],[655,21]]|
|      693 |                              []|
```

The problem is that I get None as the values of the mean and standard deviation. Most probably it happens because the code does not consider `[]`. The empty values should be substituted by 0.
Also, IntegerType should be probably a float value.

How can I get the correct result instead of None?

```
from pyspark.sql.types import IntegerType
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, col, udf, mean as mean_, stddev as stddev_

df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame(
    [(686, [[686,520.70], [645,2]]), (685, [[685,45.556], [678,23],[655,21]]), (693, [])],
    ["product_PK", "products"]
)

get_score = udf(lambda x: x[1], IntegerType())

df_stats = df.withColumn('exploded', explode(col('products')))\
    .withColumn('score', get_score(col('exploded')))\
    .select(
        mean_(col('score')).alias('mean'),
        stddev_(col('score')).alias('std')
    )\
    .collect()

mean = df_stats[0]['mean']
std = df_stats[0]['std']

print([mean, std])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need a UDF to fetch an item from the array

Second, just use `na.fill` to fill NULL values with a number (zero in your case)

```
df.withColumn("exploded" , explode(col("products") ) )
  .withColumn("score", col("exploded").getItem(1) )
  .na.fill(0)
  .select( 
           mean_(col("score") ).alias("mean") , 
           stddev_(col("score") ).alias("stddev") 
          )
  .show()

+----+------------------+
|mean|            stddev|
+----+------------------+
| 9.2|11.734564329364767|
+----+------------------+
```

To get the values separately in a variable :

```
row = df.withColumn("exploded" , explode(col("products") ) )
        .withColumn("score", col("exploded").getItem(1) )
        .na.fill(0)
        .select( 
           mean_(col("score") ).alias("mean") , 
           stddev_(col("score") ).alias("stddev") 
         )
        .first()

mean = row.mean
stddev = row.stddev
```

Comment: Ok, very useful. What if I want to ignore those empty values instead of filling them out with 0? Is there any easy way to delete them?

Comment: You can filter on `where score is not null` instead of doing `na.fill(0)` before you proceed with the computation.

Comment: Do you mean something like this?: `where(col("score").isNotNull())`

Comment: Yep, exactly like that.

Comment: I get this error: `pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: u"Field name should be String Literal, but it's 1;"`.

Comment: I think you have `struct` in your dataframe instead of array. Just do a `printSchema` on the exploded dataframe and select whatever is the name of the second value. It should look something like `col("exploded").getItem("col2")`

Comment: Ok, I figured out the column name, but now `mean` is equal to `Column<mean['mean']>`

Comment: @Markus Check now.

Comment: Thanks, but I still get the error: `File "/mnt/yarn/usercache/hdfs/appcache/application_1512391881474_3113/container_1512391881474_3113_01_000001/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/types.py", line 1504, in __getattr__` at this line `std = row.std`

Comment: Oh, that's because it should be `stddev`, not `std`. Let me check it again.